# Cant close the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use these libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

And I have a hidden form that only shows if I click the button. But I can't close it.

I find this example in the Internet and I have tried to implement it in my page.

Need help, I have tried a lot and nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<a href="#" class="closest"><img src="icon/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
  <form method="post" class="signin" action="#">
        <legend>Contacto</legend>
        <fieldset class="textbox">
        <label class="Nome">
        <span>Nome</span>
        <input id="nome" name="nome" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Nome">
        </label>
        <label class="Email">
        <span>Email</span>
        <input id="email" name="email" value="" type="email" placeholder="nome@dominio.com">
        </label>
        <label class="Mensagem">
        <span>Mensagem</span>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="56" name="mensagem" id="comment" id="mensagem" placeholder="A sua mensagem..."></textarea></label>

        <button type="submit" class="submitbutton" style="width:80px;height:30px">Enviar</button>      
        </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.login-window').click(function() {

            //Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});
// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your selectors; you probably want to change `$('a.close, #mask')` to `$('a.closest, #mask')`.

Also, `.live()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7, use `.bind()` instead.

Made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fhuNd/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a proper jquery selector, i.e. The jquery selector you have used doesn't point to any element in your page, hence it doesn't work.

use `$('a.closest')`

Comment: how can i fixed it?  sorry im new in jquery